# How to create my own filter in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, filter

I need to be able to do very specific stuff like :

```
-inside the selection, select pixels that have a color saturation above a treshold X, 
-then replace those pixels with the average pixel that have a color saturation below threshold X in a radius of Y
```

Basically this removes colors on a gray background. Do you know if it's possible to program such a filter in photoshop ? Or maybe there is an existing filter that does that ?

Comment: Yes its possible.

Comment: You may not need a filter.  Can you show an example of what you want to do?  It's hard to tell what you are trying to do without seeing anything.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of free plugin about color correction, maybe you will find what you want :

http://color-correction-plugin-for-photoshop.en.informer.com/

I know it's easier using the GIMP beceause of the scripting console, but it requires programmation skills. Also check this [website](https://web.archive.org/web/20160323084416/http://tomkrcha.com:80/?p=3896) if you are interested in creating your own script.

Comment: I love programmation.

Comment: check this : http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.15/15.04/PhotoshopPlug-InsPart1/index.html
I'd love to see your plugin in action when it's done

Comment: now I think about it there is ImageJ for scientific image analysis, do you guys know whether it has good scripting capability ?